# Show $\mathbb{E}_1\big[S_n\textbf{1}_{\{T_{\text{hit zero}} > n\}}\big] \not\to 0$ for SSRW.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose we have a simple symmetric random walk starting at $1$, and define
$$T_{\text{hit zero}} = \min\{n\geq 1 : S_n = 0\}.$$
I was trying to argue that
$$\star =\mathbb{E}_1\big[S_n\textbf{1}_{\{T_{\text{hit zero}} > n\}}\big] \not\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

I can think of it with using the FKG inequality, as the expectation can be lower bounded by
$$ \star \geq \sqrt{n} \; \mathbb{P}_1( \{S_n \geq \sqrt n\}\cap \{T_{\text{hit zero}}>n\}).$$
Both events are increasing (if we flip any of the steps from a $-1$ to $1$, they are more likely to happen), and so we get
$$\star\geq \sqrt n \; \mathbb{P}_1\{S_n \geq \sqrt n\} \mathbb{P}_1\{T_{\text{hit zero}}>n\} \geq \sqrt n C_1 \frac{C_2}{\sqrt n} > \epsilon.$$

Is there an easy to to show this claim without FKG inequality?

Comment: In my experience, saying a sequence of events $A_n$ is increasing means $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$.  In your case, one sequence is neither decreasing nor increasing and the other is decreasing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:**  $\star_n =1$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

**Proof:** I assume we walk over the integers, $S_n$ is the integer location at time $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$, and $S_0=1$. Then
$$ S_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \quad \forall n\in \{1, 2,3, ...\}$$
where $\{X_i\}$ are i.i.d. with $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=-1]=1/2$ for all $i$.
Thus
$$E[S_n] = 1 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ....\}$$
For each $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define $H_k$ as the event that we first hit zero at time $k$.  Define $G_k$ as the event that we have not yet hit 0 up to and including time $k$.  Then for any $n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we obtain
\begin{align}
1 &= E[S_n] \\
&= E[S_n|G_n]P[G_n]+\sum_{k=1}^{n}E[S_n|H_k]P[H_k] \\
&=E[S_n|G_n]P[G_n]\\
&= E[S_n 1_{G_n}]\\
&= \star_n
\end{align}
where we have used the fact that $E[S_n|H_k]=0$ for $n\geq k$. Thus, $\star_n =1$ for all positive integers $n$.  Finally, it is clear that $\star_0=1$. $\Box$